# it compiles ok but when I try to run it with a digit it says segmentation fault what do I do?

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{ // see if it is correct input if not then reset and print the right way
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(argv[1]))
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // cipher the text
        int k = atoi(argv[1]);
        string plaintext = get_string("Plain text: ");
        printf("Cipher text: ");

        // printing out the ciphered text
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(plaintext); j++)
            if (isupper(plaintext[j]))
            {
                printf("%c", (plaintext[j] - 65 + k) % 26 + 65);
            }

            else if (islower(plaintext[j]))
            {
                printf("%c", (plaintext[j] - 97 + k) % 26 + 97);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", plaintext[j]);
            }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

the problem is that when I run it as it should be it only says segmentation fault. I think that the problem is at the top but im not sure

Comment: `if (!isdigit(argv[1]))` should be puking a warning, or better, an error, at you. You're sending a `char*` to a function expecting an `int`. And I honestly don't understand the purpose of the loop `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)` in the first place. If someone types in `10` for a 10-char shift, what possible reason is there for iterating this thing *twice* ?

Comment: *it compiles ok* simply means that the syntax is correct; it does not mean that the code is actually correct. Use a debugger to step through the code to see what's happening and where things are going wrong. If you don't know how to use a debugger, now is the perfect time to start learning - the debugger is the most powerful tool a coder has available to them.

Comment: I am unsure why you are getting a segmentation fault with the code you posted. If I had to guess it would have something to do with the `isdigit()` function being passed a value outside of the range 0–127. (As already noted to you, you passed it a `char *`. Paying attention to types is important, especially for the functions in `ctype.h`, which are, sadly, not very bullet-proof.)

Answer (score 0):

Most of your problem is simply trying to deal with the logic needed to handle that argument Cipher key. Remember, it is an input like any other, so it should be treated first, separately.

Also, avoid aliases for standard objects. It does absolutely nothing to improve readability. (It does the opposite, in fact. Any C programmer will first ask: “what is different about a `string` and a `char *`?” And then spend time only to figure out that there isn’t any. So, don’t do that.)

Finally, avoid magic numbers when dealing with character strings. Just use the character literal directly. It makes life *so* much easier when reading the code.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])  // DON’T use aliases like “string” for “char *”
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    int k = atoi(argv[1]); // try to turn the argument string into the Caesar offset value
    if (k == 0)            // fail if non-numeric input (or if input is actually “0”)
    {
        printf("Invalid key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    const char * plaintext = get_string("Plain text: ");

    // Convert the plaintext to the ciphertext
    printf("Cipher text: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(plaintext); j++)
    {                                            // <-- don’t forget compound statement braces
        if (isupper(plaintext[j]))
        {
            printf("%c", (plaintext[j] - 'A' + k) % 26 + 'A');  // prefer 'A' instead of 65
        }
        else if (islower(plaintext[j]))
        {
            printf("%c", (plaintext[j] - 'a' + k) % 26 + 'a');
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", plaintext[j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Apart from those minor problems, you did a pretty good job! Keep it up!

**EDIT**
Oh yeah, almost forgot. Did you need to `free(plaintext)` before `main()` terminates?